# Powershell: Some SIDs don't translate

Tags: windows, shell, powershell

I'm trying to export User right assignment with this command:
 `secedit /export /areas USER_RIGHTS /cfg d:\privs.txt` 
And then using Powershell I'm trying to translate SIDs to names. Here is my code:

```
$output=@()
$temp = "c:\"
$file = "$temp\privs.txt"
[string] $readableNames

$process = [diagnostics.process]::Start("secedit.exe", "/export /cfg $file /areas USER_RIGHTS")
$process.WaitForExit()
$in = get-content $file

foreach ($line in $in) {
    if ($line.StartsWith("Se")) {
    $privilege = $line.substring(0,$line.IndexOf("=") - 1)
    switch ($privilege){
    "SeCreateTokenPrivilege " {$privilege = "Create a token object"}
    "SeAssignPrimaryTokenPrivilege" {$privilege = "Replace a process-level token"}
    "SeLockMemoryPrivilege" {$privilege = "Lock pages in memory"}
    "SeIncreaseQuotaPrivilege" {$privilege = "Adjust memory quotas for a process"}
    "SeUnsolicitedInputPrivilege" {$privilege = "Load and unload device drivers"}
    "SeMachineAccountPrivilege" {$privilege = "Add workstations to domain"}
    "SeTcbPrivilege" {$privilege = "Act as part of the operating system"}
    "SeSecurityPrivilege" {$privilege = "Manage auditing and the security log"}
    "SeTakeOwnershipPrivilege" {$privilege = "Take ownership of files or other objects"}
    "SeLoadDriverPrivilege" {$privilege = "Load and unload device drivers"}
    "SeSystemProfilePrivilege" {$privilege = "Profile system performance"}
    "SeSystemtimePrivilege" {$privilege = "Change the system time"}
    "SeProfileSingleProcessPrivilege" {$privilege = "Profile single process"}
    "SeCreatePagefilePrivilege" {$privilege = "Create a pagefile"}
    "SeCreatePermanentPrivilege" {$privilege = "Create permanent shared objects"}
    "SeBackupPrivilege" {$privilege = "Back up files and directories"}
    "SeRestorePrivilege" {$privilege = "Restore files and directories"}
    "SeShutdownPrivilege" {$privilege = "Shut down the system"}
    "SeDebugPrivilege" {$privilege = "Debug programs"}
    "SeAuditPrivilege" {$privilege = "Generate security audit"}
    "SeSystemEnvironmentPrivilege" {$privilege = "Modify firmware environment values"}
    "SeChangeNotifyPrivilege" {$privilege = "Bypass traverse checking"}
    "SeRemoteShutdownPrivilege" {$privilege = "Force shutdown from a remote system"}
    "SeUndockPrivilege" {$privilege = "Remove computer from docking station"}
    "SeSyncAgentPrivilege" {$privilege = "Synchronize directory service data"}
    "SeEnableDelegationPrivilege" {$privilege = "Enable computer and user accounts to be trusted for delegation"}
    "SeManageVolumePrivilege" {$privilege = "Manage the files on a volume"}
    "SeImpersonatePrivilege" {$privilege = "Impersonate a client after authentication"}
    "SeCreateGlobalPrivilege" {$privilege = "Create global objects"}
    "SeTrustedCredManAccessPrivilege" {$privilege = "Access Credential Manager as a trusted caller"}
    "SeRelabelPrivilege" {$privilege = "Modify an object label"}
    "SeIncreaseWorkingSetPrivilege" {$privilege = "Increase a process working set"}
    "SeTimeZonePrivilege" {$privilege = "Change the time zone"}
    "SeCreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege" {$privilege = "Create symbolic links"}
    "SeDenyInteractiveLogonRight" {$privilege = "Deny local logon"}
    "SeRemoteInteractiveLogonRight" {$privilege = "Allow logon through Terminal Services"}
    "SeServiceLogonRight" {$privilege = "Logon as a service"}
    "SeIncreaseBasePriorityPrivilege" {$privilege = "Increase scheduling priority"}
    "SeBatchLogonRight" {$privilege = "Log on as a batch job"}
    "SeInteractiveLogonRight" {$privilege = "Log on locally"}
    "SeDenyNetworkLogonRight" {$privilege = "Deny Access to this computer from the network"}
    "SeNetworkLogonRight" {$privilege = "Access this Computer from the Network"}
    "SeDenyBatchLogonRight" {$privilege = "Deny log on as a batch job"}
    "SeDenyServiceLogonRight" {$privilege = "Deny log on as a service"}
    "SeDenyRemoteInteractiveLogonRight" {$privilege = "Deny log on through Remote Desktop Services"}
 }
$sids = $line.substring($line.IndexOf("=") + 1,$line.Length - ($line.IndexOf("=") + 1))
$sids =  $sids.Trim() -split ","


$readableNames = ""
    foreach ($str in $sids){
            if($str.StartsWith("*"))
            {
                $str = $str.substring(1)
                $str
                $sid = new-object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier($str)
                $readableName = $sid.Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount])
                $readableNames = $readableNames + $readableName.Value + ", "
            }
            else
            {
            $readableNames = $readableNames + $str + ", "
            }
     }
    $output += New-Object PSObject -Property @{            
    privilege       = $privilege               
    readableNames   = $readableNames.substring(0,($readableNames.Length - 1))
    #else            = $line."property" 
    } 
 }
}

$output
```

So the Problem I have Is that I'm getting error
 `exception calling translate with 1 argument some or all identity referances could not be translated`

`$str` output shows me that when SIDs like 
`S-1-5-21-1042109134-4285797005-3901271436-1004` 
 `S-1-5-21-1042109134-4285797005-3901271436-1006` 
`S-1-5-21-1042109134-4285797005-3901271436-1007`
 are given to
 `$sid.Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount])`
function that causes errors. I can't understand why these SIDS cause errors. Little bit of search showed me that third number (for example in SIDs above number 21) represesents domain identity. But in the output I get there are SIDS which have different third number. For example there are:
`S-1-5-20`
`S-1-5-19`
I can't get why do these numbers differ because I'm not part of any domain. It would be nice if someone explained it. Thank you very much.
**P.S**
I've tried `wmic useraccount get name,sid` which would generate every name of the users and its corresponding SID and in the output there is no 
`S-1-5-21-1042109134-4285797005-3901271436-1004` 
 `S-1-5-21-1042109134-4285797005-3901271436-1006` 
`S-1-5-21-1042109134-4285797005-3901271436-1007`
But From where do they come from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`S-1-5-21` is the prefix used for both local and domain users. It's the next part of the SID that determine which domain it belongs to and the computer has it's own domain-identifier. If you have SIDs that won't translate in your user right assignments then it's a user or group that has been deleted (orphaned SIDs). Steps to reproduce:

1. Create a local group
2. Use gpedit.msc to a assign it a privilege in User Right Assignment
3. Delete local group
4. Run script and watch the error.

`S-1-5-20` (Network Service) and `S-1-5-19` (Local Service) are well known SIDs for special built-in accounts in Windows.

Use `try {} catch {}` to handle the exceptions from orphaned SIDs.

```
try {
    $readableName = $sid.Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount])
    $readableName
} catch {
    Write-Host "Could not find SID"
}
```

Comment: thank you very much. If i'm not part of any domain do I have domain identifier? and If yes why where is it used?

Comment: The local computer has a domain identifier to make it stand out from other domains etc. SIDs are used for permissions locally even if your not in a domain. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Identifier for a description of the SID-format

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding but, as I get for example user with this SID `S-1-5-21-1042109134-4285797005-3901271436-1004` is deleted but it was from other domain whose identifier is `21-1042109134-4285797005-3901271436`?

Comment: the domain(or computer) identifier is `1042109134-4285797005-3901271436`. If your computer has never been joined to a domain then it would be the same as it is in the SID for your own local account which you can find using `[System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().user.value`